# VBA divide by 1000 without deleting formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using this basic code to divide the value of a cell by 1000:

```
Sub Divide_by_1000()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Selection
        cell = cell / 1000
    Next
End Sub
```

Whilst it works very well for hard-coded numbers, if used on a cell with a formula in it, it removes the formula and outputs a number.

Ideally, I would like the macro to work as it does for a cell with a number in it, but for a cell with a formula I would like it to wrap brackets around the current formula and put a `/1000` at the end (i.e. keeping the formula in tact)

I believe there will need to be a test to check if the cell has a formula in it first and apply the code I already have if it doesn't and the code I outlined above if it does.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to actually change the cell values, or could you simply format the cells to display in thousands?

Comment: Hi Rory, actually change the cell values (i.e. if the cell contains the number 5, it would become 0.005) but if it contained "=(2+3)" it would become "=((2+3)/1000)"

Comment: That's a shame - the custom number format `0.##,` would divide by 1000.  [custom-number-formats-multiply-divide-by-any-power-of-10](https://chandoo.org/wp/custom-number-formats-multiply-divide-by-any-power-of-10/) - both 5 and =2+3 return 0.005 _displayed_ in the cell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if the cell has a formula by checking if the first character is a equal sign `=`

```
If Left$(cell.Formula, 1) = "=" Then
```

or even better

```
If cell.HasFormula Then
```

and then rewrite the formula extended by `( … )/1000`

```
cell.Formula = "=(" & Right$(cell.Formula, Len(cell.Formula) - 1) & ")/1000"
```

also I recommend to check if the `cell.Value` is a number before you divide by 1000

```
ElseIf IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
   cell.Value = cell.Value / 1000
```

So you end up with something like

```
If Left$(cell.Formula, 1) = "=" Then
    cell.Formula = "=(" & Right$(cell.Formula, Len(cell.Formula) - 1) & ")/1000"
ElseIf IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
    cell.Value = cell.Value / 1000
End If
```

*Note while this will work for normal formulas, it will crush eg array formulas.*

Comment: Just to clarify, what do you mean by array formulas?

Comment: These: [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7)

Comment: Why not test with `cell.HasFormula`? That will catch both array and non-array formulas

Comment: @tom of course you can, but it will still crush the array formulas, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I may have misunderstood what you meant by crush. I was reading it as it wouldn't work. Is there any advantage to testing for just an equals sign at the beginning of the string rather than using the built-in function?

Comment: @Tom Don't think there is any advantage. Actually I didn't remember `.HasFormula` :) But the re-writing of the formula is the issue here. Because I don't know a way to make this possible for array formulas.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Have a look at my answer below. I've used `.HasArray` to test for whether it is an array formula or not as well

Answer (score 3):

After comments with [@PEH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3219613/p%E1%B4%87%CA%9C):

You can use `.HasFormula` and `.HasArray` to test for the formula type

```
If cell.HasFormula Then
    If cell.HasArray Then
        cell.Offset(0, 1).FormulaArray = "=(" & Right$(cell.FormulaArray, Len(cell.FormulaArray) - 1) & ")/1000"
    Else
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=(" & Right$(cell.Formula, Len(cell.Formula) - 1) & ")/1000"
    End If
ElseIf IsNumeric(cell.Value2) Then
    cell.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = cell.Value2 / 1000
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

A range/cell can be checked for formulas using the HasFormula property e.g.

```
Dim TheArea as range
Set TheArea = range("some name")

If TheArea.HasFormula then
    '  All the cells in the range have a formula
End if
```

alternatively you could use the specialcells property of a range e.g.

```
For Each Cell In TheArea.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Cell.Value = cell.Value/1000
Next Cell

For Each Cell In TheArea.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    Cell.Formula = "=(" & Right$(Cell.Formula, Len(Cell.Formula) - 1) & ")/1000"
Next Cell
```

This approach also gives you the opportunity to detect other possible scenarios e.g. xlCellTypeBlanks if they are important to you.  The full list of special cells can be found here ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells