# Dividing all cells by 1000 expect those that contain "Sum" formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to divide all the cells in a selection by 1000 but not cells which have a sum formula.

Criteria:

1. Cell must have a number.
2. Cell should not contain the `Sum()` formula (any other formula is okay).

If both of these criteria are met then divide the cell value by 1000.

```vb
For Each cell In Selection.Cells
    If IsNumeric(cell) = False Or cell.Address = Left(ActiveCell.Formula, 5) = "=Sum(" Or cell.Address = Left(ActiveCell.Formula, 6) = "=+SUM(" Or cell.Address = Left(ActiveCell.Formula, 6) = "=-SUM(" Then
        MsgBox ("Selection either does contain numbers or has only sum formulae")
    Else
        cell.value = cell.value / 1000
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve with

> Cell.Address = Left(ActiveCell.Formula,5) = "=Sum(

You can only compare one value with another.

I'm sure the more advanced people here will frown on the way I phrased the if statement but it does the job:

```vb
Sub divideBy1000()
    Dim formCheck As Variant
    For Each ccell In Selection.Cells
        Debug.Print (ccell.Formula)
        Debug.Print (ccell.Value)
        formCheck = InStr(ccell.Formula, "SUM(") 'This checks if SUM is in the formula and returns a value bigger than 0 if so (where it occurs in the string).
        If len(trim(ccell.value2))>0 Then
            If IsNumeric(ccell.Value) And (formCheck = Null Or formCheck = 0) Then
            'You have to use AND so none of the SUM formulas get through, no else needed this way
                If Left$(ccell.Formula, 1) = "=" Then 'EDIT to keep your formula
                    ccell.Formula = "=(" & Right$(ccell.Formula, Len(ccell.Formula) - 1) & ")/1000"                    
                Else
                    ccell.Value = ccell.Value / 1000
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next ccell
End Sub
```

Edit:
Added a catch for empty cells so they don't turn to 0 and added Instr to check for the SUM as suggested by @Marcucciboy2

Comment: You could make it more legible using `InStr()` but it wouldn't necessarily improve the function

Comment: Been checking with you suggestion and while it did what it should, I probably also should add Len(ccell) > 0 since I noticed empty cells getting through IsNumeric()

Comment: yeah i'd put it above the initial if `If len(trim(ccell.value2))>0 Then `

Comment: Alright, cheers, adjusted as needed. Quick question though, is there a specific reason why you opted for the value2?

Comment: It can be slower https://stackoverflow.com/a/17363466/2727437

Comment: Thanks for helping me learn as well :)

Comment: Hi Notus_Panda, thanks for the answer. It works well.
I made a small change instead of "SUM" I made it "SUM(" because I want the macro to divide the cells which contain "SUMIF" formula. But now since it works I realized there is another problem, I want the macro to divide the cell value by 1000 but keep the existing formula in place. E.g. If cell has "Sumif(xx,yy,zz)" then it should do "(Sumif(xx,yy,zz)/1000)

Comment: This should be able to help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53481104/vba-divide-by-1000-without-deleting-formula

Comment: Thank you so much Notus_Panda and also Marcucciboy2!!!!! :) :)